# Can I dynamically create storage structs?

Tags: solidity, remix, struct

I want a function that creates document in my contract. I removed anything unnecessary. Goes like this:

```
contract MyContract{
  mapping (uint => document) documents;

  struct document{
      address author;
      bytes32 hashedContent;
  }

  function addDocument(bytes32 docHash) public{
      document newDoc = document (msg.sender,docHash); //*
      [...]
  }
}
```

Documents are structs, and I want to create them from a function and then permanently add the to a mapping. I have an error at the `//*` line saying:

`MyContract.document memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct MyContract.document storage pointer.
        document newDoc = document (docHash,msg.sender);
        ^---------------------------------------------^`

(from Remix)
The left part is storage but I think the left part is memory.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

- If so, what did I do wrong?
- If not, do you know a workaround? (Someone suggested that I do a separate contract for every document but it would complicate everything A LOT considering the rest of my contract and preferably **I'm looking for a solution in a single contract**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
documents[whateverInt] = document(msg.sender,docHash);
```

If you absolutely need to declare the document before setting it, you need to do this:

```
document memory newDoc = document(msg.sender,docHash);
documents[whateverInt] = (doc);
```

Otherwise `newDoc` will default to being a storage pointer, but the `document(msg.sender,docHash)` will be a value and not a pointer.

Comment: Pushing a memory structs in a storage mapping converts it to storage?

Comment: In a way. More accurately, document(msg.sender, docHash) isn't treated as a memory pointer or a storage pointer, it's a value. If you assign the value to a memory pointer, it works correctly, but if you assign it to a storage pointer, it will overwrite something dangerously.

Comment: It gives me the following error: `TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in mapping(uint256 => address)`

Comment: Oops! See my edit. I answered as if you were pushing to an array, not using a mapping.